# Where to put enums in my react application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react application, I have to use several enums. How should I structure them in my application? What I have done is, I created enums.js file under my config folder, and set enums like this.

```
export const USER_TYPES = {
    USER: "user",
    TRAINER: "trainer",
    ADMIN: "admin"
}

export const USER_STATUS = {
    FOLLOW: "Follow",
    REQUESTED: "Requested",
    FOLLOWING: "Following"
}

export const FOLLOWING_STATUS = {
    FOLLOW: -1,
    REQUESTED: 0,
    FOLLOWING: 1 
}
```

Is this a good way of doing this?

Comment: explain more what is the purpose of it? cause it's kinda abstract question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a more semantic use, you could rename and move your file from `config/enum.js` to `constants/users.js`.

There you export each object your want, but with a shortened name:
`USER_TYPE` -> `TYPES`, `USER_STATUS` -> `STATUS`.

So when you import your file you can do: `import * as USERS from 'constants/users;` and use it like this: `USERS.STATUS.FOLLOW`.

Comment: Do these have to be in a separate file?

Answer (score 2):

if I understand correctly what you need....
in one of your file like newfile.js you have to import your enum file like this:

```
import { USER_TYPES, USER_STATUS,FOLLOWING_STATUS } from './enums'
```

note: './enums' is a path ... so here you have to put your path

and use as normal constant like this:

```
USER_TYPES.USER // is it  string  "user",
USER_TYPES.TRAINER // is it  string  "trainer",
USER_TYPES.ADMIN // is it  string  "admin",

USER_STATUS.REQUESTED //is it  string  "Requested",

FOLLOWING_STATUS.FOLLOWING //is it  number 1,
```